# Django - Change the default invalid email error message in ModelForm

Tags: django

I'm using a `ModelForm` to save users. The User model is the default `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. My `ModelForm` class is like this

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    password = CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    confirm_password = CharField(label="Confirm your password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
        labels = {
            'username': 'User name',
            'email': 'E-mail',
        }
        widgets = {
            'username': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

When I do a request with an invalid email in the form, I have in `RegisterForm.email.errors` the message "Enter a valid email address."

How do I change this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', 
                         error_messages={'invalid': 'You custom error message', })
```